# Custom Taxonomy Archive page is not showing when clicking on <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $term_link ); ?>"></a>

Tags: custom-taxonomy

```
    <?php
/**
 * Template Name: Taxonomy Listing
 * This file lists taxonomies on a page. Based on http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link
 *
 * @author Subhasish Nath
 * @link http://subhasishlive.com
 */
get_header();
?>

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="container">
                    <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="clearfix header-txt">
                            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                <h3 class="green-heading wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
                                <?php the_title(); ?>
                                </h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="clearfix header-txt">
                            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                <div class="product-list-wrapper">
                                    <ul>
                                    <?php 
                                    $taxonomies = get_terms( array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'producttypes',
                                        'orderby' => 'name',
                                        'hide_empty' => false
                                    ) );
                                    if ( !empty($taxonomies) ) :
                                        foreach( $taxonomies as $category ) {
                                    ?>

                                        <li class="wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
                                            <div class="pr_item">
                                                <?php $term_link = get_term_link( $category ); ?>
                                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $term_link ); ?>">
                                            <figure>
                                              <img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($category->term_id); ?>" alt="<?php echo $category->name; ?>" class="image-item img-responsive" />
                                              <div class="overlay">
                                                <div class="text green-heading"><?php echo $category->name; ?></div>
                                              </div>
                                              </figure>
                                              </a>
                                                <h3><?php echo $category->name; ?></h3>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <?php 
                                        }
                                        endif;

                                        ?>

                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

> Clicking on the hyperlink takes me to the following page with "page
>   not found" error.
>   http://vicecream.co.in/producttypes/cones/
>
> Even though I have created taxonomy-producttypes-cones.php template

[image]

> Then how to make a template where `<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $term_link ); ?>"></a>` can redirect me.

Comment: Did you flush the rewrite rules?

Comment: Thanks a lot.Now it works fine.I just forgot that trick.Now feeling stupid.

Comment: @SubhasishNath happens to the best of us